# Converting browser CSS to android

Tags: android, user-interface

Convert a simple Cascading Style Sheets file into the android Cascading Style Sheets file to display the HTML page into android application using Web view.

Comment: Wt u need exactly.. There is android css.. There are some attributes like media which use full in android environment

Comment: I want to create an android application and want to display web page in android application using web view. but i am unable to view the web page properly due to CSS.

Comment: Kindly provide suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi first I would like you go through all the apis version in android with respect their support to html elements, css and javascript. Since there you will come across couple issues how html is supported by webview(with respect to api level). It varies across devices and mainly concerning factor is device screen density. But with help of some tags like media, viewport you can come up with uncertainties.If trying handle landscape and portrait modes you need have responsive themes. To start of your coding go through following links

[link 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html)

[link 2](http://nativecss.com/docs/tutorials/intro/android)

[link 3](http://nativecss.com/)

[responsive android theme](http://www.browserstack.com/responsive)